# Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED+MANIFEST_MALFORMED in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I am getting this error

`ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl61481456.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #44): crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseMessagingService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]`

After installing "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base version: 71.1610.0" for the dependency of the plugin.firebasepushnotification

Target Android version 12.0 (API Level 31 - S)

Here is my menifest.xml code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.0.2" package="com.healholmes" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application tools:replace="android:label" android:label="Heal Holmes" android:icon="@mipmap/icon_ambush" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base version: 71.1610.0` is too old. According to the error message, there is a service named `PNFirebaseMessagingService` in your project doesn't declare the `exported` property.

It should be created by the nuget package you added in your project. So you can try to use the newest version of `plugin.firebasepushnotification` and the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base`.

Such as `plugin.firebasepushnotification version 3.4.35` and `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base version 118.1.0`